# cd'ing to a freshly cloned repository

Tags: git, shell, cd

I have just written this function in a Shell Script:

```
clone_and_dev() {
  REPO=$1
  echo
  echo "Beginning process for the $REPO repository..."
  git clone git@github.com:keyfer/$REPO.git
  cd "$REPO"
}
```

The problem lies with that the `cd` command does not seem to work. I'm wondering if there is a way to make this work.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this contained in a script and you run the script like `./script` or `bash script`? If yes, `cd` has no effect because it happens in a subshell, which cannot affect the parent shell. If however "no effect" is meant for a function call within the same script, then I'm not sure.

Comment: @benjamin This is a executable file in ~/bin which then call by just running `clonescipt` in terminal. There are other parts of this script though, which call the function and pass param.

Comment: Then it can't change the directory for you, see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [BashFAQ 60](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/060).

Comment: I remove PowerShell, it's not envolved here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't "cd" work in a bash shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a **start cmd /k** 
or 
**start cmd /k "place commands for new window here"**
see:

```
clone_and_dev() {
  REPO=$1
  echo
  echo "Beginning process for the $REPO repository..."
  git clone git@github.com:keyfer/$REPO.git
  cd "$REPO"
  start cmd /k
}
```