# Newbie: Script to change directories

Tags: linux, scripting, ksh

The following is a snippet of a larger script I'm attempting. I just want this part to recognize the argument is a directory and then cd to that directory: i.e ./larj /etc.

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Filename: larj.sh

if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "0 or 1 arguments allowed."
    exit
fi
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "directory only."
    exit
else
    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        cd $1
    fi
fi
```

When I run the script with /etc as the argument, it appears nothing happens; it stays in the same directory with no error.
Anyone have any suggestions how to get it to change directories?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you simply use `cd`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't "cd" work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem why you `cd` can't work is that `cd` executes in the `sub-shell` when you execute the script as `./larj /etc`. So when you execute the script, it changes the working directory of the subshell and has no impact on the current shell.

So you can execute it as `. ./larj /etc`.

Refer to [Why doesn't “cd” work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script).

Comment: Ok. That makes sense - subshell. As I mentioned, this is just a snippet of the larger script. So, the snippet is fine. When I add it to the larger script, it should cd to the directory in the argument, perform its function, and return the results at the shell where I am working? Is that accurate?

Comment: @T2true. Yes, it works well. You can test by a small bash script which contains only `cd /tmp && mkdir -p test` to check whether the `test` directory exists. Then you will find that it works well.

Answer (score 1):

The cd is taking place within the script's shell.

When the script ends, it's shell exits, and you return to the directory before running the script. In order to change the directory you can

```
mkdir testdir
. ./your_script.sh testdir
```

At the end of the script you will be moved at directory testdir.