# How can I use a path in a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

[I would like to store the path of a file typed by the user in a variable and then use it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXVK6.png)

[image]

Comment: See [why doesn't cd work in a bash shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo "read es: " $1 
dirname $1
```

command line is **./bashName.sh path**

Answer (score -1):

Use `dirname` to get just path for any "file".

Example:

```
$ read -p "Please type file full path: " myVar
Please type file full path: /tmp/bla/bla/file
$ dirname "${myVar}"
/tmp/bla/bla
```