# Why is change dir (cd) not working in this mac script?

Tags: bash

I have this script in a file called /Users/tcl/scripts/gotoroot:

```
echo "hello"
cd /
echo "good bye"
```

But when I run it I get this:

```
User:scripts tcl$ pwd
/Users/tcl/scripts
User:scripts tcl$ gotoroot
hello
good bye
User:scripts tcl$ pwd
/Users/tcl/scripts
User:scripts tcl$
```

The directory has not changed and I don't know why? It should be /, not /Users/tcl/scripts

Answer (score 6):

When you run the script, it starts a subshell in a new process. The `cd` changes directory inside that subshell, not inside your terminal process.

Test it out by putting this in your script:

```
pwd
cd /
pwd
```

You should see that it changes to `/` inside the script.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script.

Answer (score 2):

Shell scripts are run inside of sub processes. The CD is working but it's happening inside a different process than your main terminal session and has no effect on the working directory once you return to your terminal session.