# Why can't my shell function change directory from piped input?

Tags: bash, cd

I have made a cli which computes the location of a certain directory, and I would really like to have the script change into it. My first approach was `./myscript | cd` which I've learned doesn't work as 1. `cd` doesn't take piped arguments, and 2. the script won't be allowed to change the directory of the parent shell.

I learned that there are workarounds, and I tried creating a function in `.bash_profile`:

```
function cdir(){
  DIR=""
  while read LINE; do
      DIR=$LINE
  done
  echo $DIR
  cd $DIR
}
```

Now running `./myscript | cdir` the correct directory is output, however, the directory is still not changed.

Using command substitution works: `cd $(./myscript)`, but I'd really prefer to be able to write this using pipe. Do you have any idea how I can get this to work, or at least explain why it isn't possible?

Comment: If you run `pwd` at the end of your function, you'll see that the directory *was* changed within its scope. Whether that scope matches parent scope in a pipeline in unspecified by POSIX, and varies shell-to-shell (and between various runtime configurations for a specific shell -- it's possible to get the last pipeline element run in the parent in new versions of bash, but only if you disable job control support).

Answer (score 3):

`cd` changes the current working directory, which is an attribute of the process.  When you use a pipeline, shell creates a subprocess and the effect of `cd` (inside your function) is lost when the subprocess finishes.

```
cd -- "$(./myscript)"
```

is the right way of doing it.  Here, `cd` runs in your current shell.

---

See also:

- [Why doesn't "cd" work in a bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script)
- [chdir() doesn't change directory after exiting to shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141313/chdirdirectory-doesnt-change-directory-after-exiting-to-shell) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange

Comment: Quibble -- `cd -- "$(./myscript)"` is arguably a bit more correct.

Comment: Thanks! So the piping itself is spawning a new process.