# Change directory using loop in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to change directory to perform a task in each directory. Following is the code:

```
for i in {1..10}
do
cd dir/subdir$i
bla... bla.. bla..
done
```

However I am getting error:

```
 not found [No such file or directory]
```

I have tried the following but still getting the same above error:

```
cd $(echo dir/subdir"$i")
cd $(eval dir/subdir"$i")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script

Comment: The first form is OK but you should check to make sure you're getting back to the original directory or that you're doing the cd'ing (and the operation) in a subshell (i.e., `cd dir/subdir$i; bla bla bla; cd ../..` or `(cd dir/$subdir$i; bla bla bla )`)

Comment: I am giving `cd /<the_complete_path>/subdir$i`

Comment: Also, i set `i=1` and tried `cd /dir/subdir$i` where `/dir/subdir$i` is a complete directory starting from root. Still facing the same error.

Comment: Thanks mate @PSkocik . Something weird is happening with the paths. I will sort it now. Directly giving the whole path from root isn't working for me.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is probably because all the directories you want to change into are relative from the original base directory.
One way to solve this is using a `(...)` sub-shell:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    (
    cd dir/subdir$i || continue
    cmd1
    cmd2
    )
done
```

Another way is to return to the previous directory using `cd "$OLDPWD"`:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    cd dir/subdir$i || continue
    cmd1
    cmd2
    cd "$OLDPWD"
done
```

Yet another way is to use `pushd` and `popd`:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    pushd dir/subdir$i || continue
    cmd1
    cmd2
    popd
done
```

Comment: Off-topic, therefor already upvoted:
I think `cmd1` and `cmd2` should be skipped when the `cd` fails. Perhaps suggest `cd dir/subdir$i && cmd1 && cmd2`.