# Copy specific word from a file to another file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sh

i am new to shell scripting.
my folder structure is like below format, in that every folder one file is there  the file  name is  note.json, so i want to copy from note.json specific word like "user", i tried this for single file, it's working but showing unnecessary data and also i needed in loop format (means going to every folder doing the same) can any body help me out?

my folder structure:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - zeppelin hdfs          0 2020-06-01 16:20 /user/zeppelin/notebook/2FBC2M3K2
drwxr-xr-x   - zeppelin hdfs          0 2020-05-20 18:01 /user/zeppelin/notebook/2FBDEKUGP
drwxr-xr-x   - zeppelin hdfs          0 2020-05-26 20:32 /user/zeppelin/notebook/2FBDXNZRC
drwxr-xr-x   - zeppelin hdfs          0 2020-05-26 21:00 /user/zeppelin/notebook/2FBEAGZEE
drwxr-xr-x   - zeppelin hdfs          0 2020-05-25 14:18 /user/zeppelin/notebook/2FBGXSHZR
drwxr-xr-x   - zeppelin hdfs          0 2020-05-20 14:31 /user/zeppelin/notebook/2FBHCNKJP
drwxr-xr-x   - zeppelin hdfs          0 2020-06-02 17:34 /user/zeppelin/notebook/2FBJCZ212
```

I tried for single folder using below command,

```
$ cat note.json | grep "user"
"user": "Ayan.Paul",
            "data": "org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [Ayan.Paul] does not have [USE] privilege on [snt_mmedata_upload_prd]\n\tat org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:300)\n\tat org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:286)\n\tat org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:324)\n\tat org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:265)\n\tat org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)\n\tat org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)\n\tat org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql(JDBCInterpreter.java:718)\n\tat org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.interpret(JDBCInterpreter.java:801)\n\tat org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:103)\n\tat org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:633)\n\tat org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)\n\tat org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\nCaused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied: user [Ayan.Paul] does not have [USE] privilege on [snt_mmedata_upload_prd]\n\tat org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:335)\n\tat org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:199)\n\tat org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:262)\n\tat org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:247)\n\tat org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:527)\n\tat org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:315)\n\tat org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:562)\n\tat org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1557)\n\tat org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1542)\n\tat org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.thrift.server.TServlet.doPost(TServlet.java:83)\n\tat org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftHttpServlet.doPost(ThriftHttpServlet.java:208)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:584)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:493)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:283)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:108)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)\n\t... 3 more\nCaused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.HiveAccessControlException:Permission denied: user [Ayan.Paul] does not have [USE] privilege on [snt_mmedata_upload_prd]\n\tat org.apache.ranger.authorization.hive.authorizer.RangerHiveAuthorizer.checkPrivileges(RangerHiveAuthorizer.java:483)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.doAuthorizationV2(Driver.java:1330)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.doAuthorization(Driver.java:1094)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:705)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1863)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1810)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1805)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.compileAndRespond(ReExecDriver.java:126)\n\
```

Comment: hi guys, i need only user:ayan.paul in my file,remaing unnecessary data should be removed,this process for remaing folders also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools) and [Change directory using loop in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46973632/4518341)

Comment: Although you might not need to cd in a loop. Try using a glob: `/user/zeppelin/notebook/*/note.json`

Answer (score 1):

As said above, if it is json structured the best and clean way is to use jq.
otherwise, if this line always stay the same you can try:

```
cat note.json | grep "\"user\":" | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/,//g' | sed 's/ //g'
```

where

**grep "\"user\":"** - will take the the line you wanted

**cut -d":" -f2** - will take from the second column by ":" separator

**sed 's/\"//g'** - remove "

**sed 's/,//g'** - remove commas

**sed 's/ //g'** - will remove spaces just in case ( you don't have to use it)

if you need the loop for it, lets say:

folder_Path='/path/to/myfolder'

```
files_in_folder=$(ls ${folder_Path})
for file in ${files_in_folder}
do
    if [[ ${file} == "note.json" ]]
    then
        cat ${file} | grep "\"user\":" | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/,//g' | sed 's/ //g' > ${new_file_path}
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the `note.json` file always has "user" at the beginning of a line, then you can grep for that.  It also sounds like you want the **value** of the "user" JSON field.  Try using `jq` to parse that.  Below is the "cheap and dirty" way of stripping out the extra characters.  (We'll stick with a loop because you're probably doing something other things for each file...)

```
for file in $(find . -name note.json); do
    grep "^.user" $file | cut -c 10- | tr -d '",'
done
```

If you want help with using `jq` to parse JSON, just ask a different question showing a "note.json" file and your attempt at pasring it!