# how to change directory to a path stored in variable bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to change the CD to a path stored in a variable. The variable gets its value from text stored in a file.

This gets the value inside the text file:

```
devdir=$(<\$HOME/devdir.txt)
cd $devdir
```

Inside the text file is the text: `$HOME/bin`

The error I get is:

```
/bin/dev: line 41: cd: $HOME/bin: No such file or directory
```

This is the result of trying to use the variable, compared to manually typing it:

[image: screen shot of text so you can't copy/paste it]

UPDATE:
This is the snippet of Bash given with the improvement given by fabiotk, which seems to yield no result when it is within the script, however it works fine when run in the cmd window...[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sgmr.png)

Here is the entire script so far: [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmqhg.png)
and here is me running the given line on its own, then running the script showing it doesn't work inside: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO1Bo.png)

Comment: did you mean "change the PWD to a path.." instead?

Comment: I just meant the current directory. So i want the directory the user is currently in to be changed to that which is stored in the file

Comment: *Please* don't post your information as images.  See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: If you are attempting to create a script which switches the user's current working directory, you are in for trouble. This is a FAQ. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd $(eval "echo \"$(cat $HOME/devdir.txt)\"");
```

or:

```
eval "cd \"$(cat $HOME/devdir.txt)\"";
```

It will change the directory inside the `script` session that you are running. If you run `./script` it won't `cd` externally

Comment: This looks a little bit cleaner without the backslashes: `cd $(eval 'echo "$(cat $HOME/devdir.txt)"'')`

Comment: This works perfectly in the shell, but when its in the middle of my script it just doesnt do anything :/

Comment: that's strange, are you sure you done everything right? I made a simple script here and it worked: `cd $(eval "echo \"$(cat $HOME/devdir.txt)\""); ls -la;` and the `ls` printed the contents of devdir's path

Comment: I'll add the whole script if that will show you anything useful? It should be running that section due to the echo being shown before it, but it just doesn't change the directory.

Comment: What's with the `echo`? Why not just `eval "cd '$(cat $HOME/devdir.txt)'"`?

Comment: @tripleee without the echo I ended up with the same problem as OP's

Comment: You need to `eval` some command but it might as well be the `cd` directly, which incidentally also simplifies the solution by about two orders of magnitude.

Comment: ... Though the single quotes in my comment are inhibiting that so change those to escaped double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$HOME` is not getting expanded.  If you want to expand it, the `eval` posted in another answer might help; but we generally want to avoid `eval` if we can, especially if you only need this specific variable to be expanded.

```
devdir=$(sed "s%^\$HOME/%$HOME/%" $HOME/devdir.txt)
```

Comment: So should this work if i just 'cd devdir' after implementing that section instead?

Comment: No, the syntax to expand the variable is `cd "$devdir"` (the quotes are not strictly required in this limited scenario, but we see way too many examples where people post code which is broken because they forgot the quotes).

Comment: I'm still getting that same error as the original post now with your code