# Half of a mkdir function works but cd part doesn't

Tags: linux, bash, manjaro

I've been trying do put together a function that combines mkdir and cd. This is what I've been using:

```
#!/bin/bash
mk(){
    mkdir "$1" && cd "$1"
}

mk $1
```

However, when I run the script using .`/mker.sh test` , it'll create a directory with  but won't change into it. I'm brand new to Bash so I'm really at a loss as to why that part doesn't work. It doesn't return an error to the command line either.

What's the issue here? Thanks!

Comment: Scripts run in a subprocess, so `cd` changes the directory *of the subprocess*, not your shell. Use a function (directly, not in a script). This looks like a duplicate of ["Why I can't change directories using `cd`?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-i-cant-change-directories-using-cd), but unfortunately most of the top answers there are not useful here (using an alias) or just plain bad ideas (any of the ones that try to make it work via a script). Use a function.

Answer (score 0):

When working in / with `bash` There is no  need to `cd` (it's actually considered "poor form").  `cd` is "meant" for command line usage -- Though it will work in some cases programmatically, it's easiest and best practice to *use* the directory when working with it rather than trying to `change directory` into it.

Simply "use" the full directory to do whatever you intend on "doing" with it .. IE

```
mkdir "$1" && echo "test" > $1/test.txt
```

**NOTE**

In case I read your question wrong, and you want the `shell` to `change directory` is a little trickier.  The sub-shell (or bash script) has it's own concept of directory .. So no matter "where" you tell it to `cd`, it will only apply to that sub-shell and not the main shell (or command line).  One way to get around this is to use `alias`

```
alias dir="cd $M1"
```