# Change directory in script bash

Tags: bash

I want to find a file and goto his directory. I made a bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
FILEPATH=`find . -name "$FILE"`

if [ -f "$FILEPATH" ]
then
    cd $(dirname "$FILEPATH")
fi
```

But this script does not work. I saw on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-i-cant-change-directories-using-cd) that I have to add `exec bash` or `$SHELL` but it create a new bash prompt ans display my welcome message.

How can I do ? I just want a script, alias or something to find a file and go to the directory containing that file.

Comment: Do not use the `PATH` as an ordinary variable. Change your own variables to lower case letters. By convention, capitalized variables are environment variables and shell internal variables.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin I changed the name, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source your script instead of running it like you do. When you run it like you do, you spawn a new shell that executes the `cd`, completes succesfully, closes the shell and returns to your current shell, leaving you in your `pwd`.

Use `source myscript.sh` or `. myscript.sh` instead of `bash myscript.sh` or `myscript.sh`.