# How to use bash script/CMakeLists.txt to run cmake

Tags: bash, cmake

```sh
.
|-bin
| |-Debug
|-source
|-sh
| |-runme.sh
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

Normally, I `cd bin/Debug`. Then `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../../` following `cmake --build .`

Now, I want to create a bash script `sh/runme.sh` that I can call from main `.` directory using `sh sh/runme.sh Debug`, which is intended to do the same work as described in the previous line.

My present `runme.sh`:

```
cd bin/"$1"  # of course this does not work.
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../../
cmake --build .
```

If I run `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .` following `cmake --build .` from main `.` directory, it creates `CMakeFiles/`, cache, makefile etc. relative to main `.` directory and not in the respective `bin/Debug` directory.

What and where (`CMakeLists.txt` or `sh/runme.sh`) should I change to make this work? Preferably to `CMakeLists.txt`. I want to keep main directory clean.

Comment: `# of course this does not work.` why?, do you get an error message? What does it say?

Comment: calling `cd` from bash script does not actually serve the intended purpose. [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-cant-i-change-directories-using-cd-in-a-script)

Answer (score 0):

First cd into your root repository. You could get the path to current script and be relative to it, or if you're for example using `git`, get path to root dir of git repo.

Also, you do not need to `cd` (except for `ctest`). Specify the directory to cmake.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}"/..
if (($# != 1)); then : handle errror; fi
b=bin/"$1"
cmake -S . -B "$b" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="$1"
cmake --build "$b"
```

I like doing `Makefile`s with all the shortcuts, because of the interactive completion of `make` in shell.

Comment: Thanks for the `-B`. How to call `make clean` from root repo, in this case?

Comment: `make clean from root repo, in this case?` In the case you write your own Makefile, _you_ write what `make clean` does, for me it usually does `rm -r _build`.